# How to interpret utf-8 characters within a ruby script (options_for_select) on a html.erb page

Tags: utf-8

I want to use utf-8 characters in a ruby script (options_for_select).

I've tried the following:

- Adding `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` and `# encoding: utf-8`
- `.html_safe` and `raw` - though as I'm new to ruby I may not have tried all possible combinations.

I've been trying to fix this for a day and I'm out of ideas at this point. Would appreciate a simple fix.

Thank you in advance.

Here is the ruby script before:

`<%= select_tag "quantity", options_for_select(%w(x1(&pound;49.00) x2&nbsp;(&pound;98.00) x3&nbsp;(&pound;147.00) x4&nbsp;(&pound;196.00) x5&nbsp;(&pound;245.00) x10&nbsp;(&pound;441.00) x100&nbsp;(&pound;3920.00)), 1), id: 'quantity' %>`

Here it is without the utf-8 characters:

`<%= select_tag "quantity", options_for_select(%w(x1(49.00) x2(98.00) x3(147.00) x4(196.00) x5(245.00) x10(441.00) x100(3920.00)), 1), id: 'quantity' %>`

Here's the full ruby script:

`<%= select_tag "quantity", options_for_select(%w(x1(&pound;49.00) x2&nbsp;(&pound;98.00) x3&nbsp;(&pound;147.00) x4&nbsp;(&pound;196.00) x5&nbsp;(&pound;245.00) x10&nbsp;(&pound;441.00) x100&nbsp;(&pound;3920.00)), 1), id: 'quantity' %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag "preorder", true %>
        <%= submit_tag "Checkout", :class => "blue_button disabled", :id => "amazon_button" %>
      <% end %>`

Comment: `&pound;` is not a UTF-8 character ([if such term even makes sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8))  but a concatenation of the characters `&`, `p`, `o`, `u`, `n`, `d` and `;`. What are you seeing on the web page?

Comment: Point taken, thanks for the clarification. A quick screen-grab: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/67589724/drop-down.png